# Seting up Oracle, ASP.net MVC4 and Simple MemberShip Provider

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, oracle, asp.net-mvc-4, membership-provider

I'm trying to use SimpleMemberShip Provider in my ASP.net MVC4 Application with Oracle DataBase.
So this my connection string in Web.config file:

```
 <add name="TEST.127" connectionString="DATA SOURCE=127.0.0.1:1521;PERSIST SECURITY INFO=True;USER ID=TEST;Password=1234;" providerName="Oracle.DataAccess.Client"/>
```

and This's `USERS` tabel : 
[image]

when I try to acces to Login page or Register page I got this error :

```
Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleException: ORA-00936: missing expression
```

at this line :

```
WebSecurity.InitializeDatabaseConnection("TEST.127", "Users", "UserId", "Username", autoCreateTables: true);
```

So Any one have an idea how to fix it ? 
I need to use MemberShip System in my Application without using any other database Except Oracle, I have tried to use Oracle MemberShip Provider but I failed Look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23094959/using-oracle-membership-provider-in-asp-net-mvc)